# First order description of connected components?

Tags: general-topology, logic, model-theory

Let $X\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and let $\psi=(x\in X)$, a first order formula in the language of the real field, enriched by the single predicate $(x\in X)$.

Is it possible to define the connected components using $\psi$ (and the field operations, so everything in "epsilon-delta language" is allowed)? More specifically, given $x\in X$, is there an "operator" $\mathcal{L}(\psi,x)$ on pairs of first order formulae and points in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, which doesn't depend on $X$ (!), so that the formula $\mathcal{L}(\psi,x)$ defines the connected component of $x$ in $X$? For example, the operator $\psi\mapsto\forall\epsilon\exists y\;\psi(y)\wedge\;|y-x|<\epsilon$ defines the closure of $X$, and is independent of $X$.

I truly suspect that the answer is no. However, I absolutely know nothing about logic, in fact, I'm not sure my question is even well phrased, much less to prove that one can't define the connected components of $X$ using first order formulas.

Edit: In the comments, Alex Kruckman suggested the question of whether connected components are uniformly definable. While this seems to be a more formal question, it is not completly equivalent to my question. In fact, I am asking this in regard to o-minimality, where connected components are uniformly definable - given a definable family, one can consider a cellular decomposition of its total space, and then the connected components of each fiber is a union of projections of cells from the decomposition. However, while this shows connected components are uniformly definable, it still doesn't answer my question - each family has a different cellular decomposition - so the "operator" $\mathcal{L}$ will not be universal, it will depend on the family.

Comment: Do you mean that each individual connected component can be defined using a (different) first order formula?  Or that there is a single first order formula that defines the equivalence relation on $X$ of "being in the same connected component"?  Or something else?

Comment: In addition to the clarifications Eric asks for, there is also the issue of whether you allow parameters. For example, if $X$ is the set of irrational numbers in $\mathbb{R}$, it has continuum-many connected components. Since there are only countably many first-order formulas (without parameters), you can't define all the connected components. On the other hand, if you allow parameters, you can define the connected component $\{r\}$ by $x = r$.

Comment: If you allow parameters, there is a distinction between asking whether the connected components are each individually definable (by a different formula) or whether they are *uniformly* definable, i.e., there is a single formula $\psi(x,y)$ such that each connected component is definbed by $\psi(x,b)$ for some choice of parameters $b$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I attempted to clarify my question.

Comment: @AlexKruckman After considering your comment again, I realize this is probably the formal version of my question. I will edit. Do you happen to know if they are uniformly definable?

Comment: Here is what I think could be a formal statement of your problem: if we expand the field of real numbers with a sort for all subsets and a $\in$ relation between the home sort and the subset sort, is the connected component of $x$ in $X$ uniformly (first order, of course) definable in parameters $x$ and $X$ (maybe also without any quantifiers on the set sort; I doubt this would truly matter, but using those would be against the spirit of your question, I think).

Comment: If you don't want to add a new sort (as @tomasz suggests), you can also phrase the question like this: Given a natural number $n$, is there a formula $\varphi(x,y)$ in the language $\{0,1,+,-,\times,P\}$, where $P$ is an  $n$-ary relation symbol, such that for any expansion of the real field by interpreting $P$ as a set $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, the formula $\varphi(x,y)$ defines the relation "$x$ and $y$ are in the same connected component of $X$" (so that for any $b\in X$, $\varphi(x,b)$ defines the connected component of $b$)?

Comment: I'm sure the answer to this question is no, even if we restrict to $X$ so that $(\mathbb{R},0,1,+,-,\times,X)$ is o-minimal. But I don't have a proof.